# How to light a set using coloured fluorescent lights

Tags: video, editing, lighting, filming, color-grading

Hi all i'm wanting some advice on set lighting. i'm wanting to create a set similar to the below using fluorescent lights. Just wanting to know what equipment is needed to achieve this look. Obviously there are using red fluorescent lights but how are they powered etc and some kind of blue fill light? I'll admit i'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to lighting so any advice will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apologies for replying to such an old question, but I like the shot composition so I thought I'd drop my 2c. Most of the light here is from off-camera - there are PARs behind the glass projecting the blue light in, red PARs to the left off-camera providing the light on the sides of the pillars and the back of the actor, and in the close-up they've bought in additional blue wash lighting behind camera, likely from a high angle. I think the visible tubes are primarily for show and aren't providing much of the overall scene lighting, other than for the reflections on the floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching for "LED Neon Tube".  Nowadays LEDs are so common for venue lighting, maybe the set designers might went that route.

If this is fluorescent, they could be white fluorescent bulbs wrapped in theatrical gel roll material, such as [this](https://www.stagelightingstore.com/home/31385-rosco-roscolux-120-red-diffusion-24-x-25-roll).  For the power supply (called a ballast) and housing, you can buy fluorescent bulb track lighting from any commercial lighting store. The ballasts for traditional T8 and T12 size bulbs are being phased out due to regulation.  But my local supplier still had a couple in stock a few years ago.

The bulbs could also be neon, producing a native red color without a filter.  I believe those would have to be handmade by a signage company.

Also, the shot has pretty obvious red stage lighting to the lower-left, and blue to the upper-right.  I'm judging from the red light and shadows striking the ceiling, and the diagonal blue light shadows on the actor's body.  My guess is that almost none of the light in the shot is from the vertical bulbs.

I'm a newbie at this too, but hope some of my information is accurate :)  I had a similar project for a party production a few years ago, which involved fluorescent ballasts and housings with vertically mounted blacklights.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Really helped particularly about the red stage light i hadn't noticed it but it is obvious now you mention it